# Sqoop import driver issue: Could not load driver

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, driver, sqoop

So I have been importing data from an oracle database to a hadoop cluster fro a few days now using sqoop.

Today when I try to do a sqoop import I get the following error:

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
 at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:727)
 at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
 at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:615)
 at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:638)
 at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:237)
 at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:221)
 at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:283)
 at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1268)
 at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1080)
 at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
 at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:390)
 at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
 at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
  No encryption was performed by peer.
```

For some reason the driver is not working.

I tried telling sqoop where the driver is using the -libjars option in the import command. This didn't work.

Maybe my driver file is corrupted?

Regards,
P.

Comment: Please share entire with us entire Sqoop command line and place where you put the Oracle JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with a software update. The location of the driver was moved. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong oracle driver class. Use Oracle driver class "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver". Alternatively you can also copy the oracle jdbc driver in sqoop_home/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following parameters

```
--driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```